# Bulk Channel Report has Elements with no Video ID

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, analytics

I have a few different channels where I am using bulk channel reports, and in the channel_basic_1a and 2a reports, I am noticing some elements that are getting returned with statistics, but no video_id to associate them with.

Has anybody else encountered this behavior? I have noticed this across several days, and it's a relatively small part of my total data set, but noticeable. This occurred three times on this one particular day, one in country US, one in ZZ and one in JO.

Here's an example json element:

```
 {
"date": "20150731",
"card_teaser_click_rate": "0",
"subscribed_status": "subscribed",
"card_clicks": "0",
"annotation_closable_impressions": "0",
"shares": "0",
"annotation_closes": "0",
"card_impressions": "0",
"videos_removed_from_playlists": "0",
"annotation_impressions": "0",
"annotation_clickable_impressions": "0",
"annotation_click_through_rate": "0",
"views": "0",
"likes": "0",
"annotation_clicks": "0",
"comments": "0",
"average_view_duration_seconds": "0",
"live_or_on_demand": "on_demand",
"card_teaser_clicks": "0",
"videos_added_to_playlists": "0",
"card_click_rate": "0",
"dislikes": "0",
"subscribers_lost": "0",
"watch_time_minutes": "0",
"annotation_close_rate": "0",
"card_teaser_impressions": "0",
"country_code": "US",
"average_view_duration_percentage": "0",
"channel_id": "*******",
"subscribers_gained": "10",
"video_id": ""
  },
```

Comment: Is there any error message that you got?

Comment: Nope, I'm getting 200's all the way through the process from token to job retrieval to report retrieval. Just a weird anomaly in the data.